# Haddock breaks down on #if #else #endif clauses

Tags: haskell, documentation, haddock, reflex

I am trying to generate documentations for a github library using haddock.  Here's the code I entered:

```
$ find -name '*.hs' | xargs haddock --html -o docs
src/Reflex/Dom/Xhr.hs:154:0:
     error: missing binary operator before token "("
     #if MIN_VERSION_aeson(1,0,0)
     ^
```

Then I looked up the relevant section of my source code `Xhr.hs` line 154:

```
import Data.Aeson
#if MIN_VERSION_aeson(1,0,0)
import Data.Aeson.Text
#else
import Data.Aeson.Encode
#endif
```

I didn't know `#if`, `#else` and `#endif` were part of Haskell but I could guess the meaning.  Depending on the version, the code should import either `Aeson.Text` or `Aeson.Encode`.  Just in case, I looked up the version:

```
$ ghc-pkg list | grep aeson
    aeson-0.11.3.0
```

This was enough to give haddock difficulty.  The info pages get sent to a folder called `docs` which contains a few empty html files waiting to be populated with the details of the `Reflex.Dom` library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code uses `-cpp`. Preprocessor directives are not part of the usual Haskell language. In order to correctly parse that code, you need to [specify additional options to Haddock](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/invoking.html#cpp):

> ### 2.1. Using literate or pre-processed source
>
> Since Haddock uses GHC internally, both plain and literate Haskell sources are accepted without the need for the user to do anything. **To use the C pre-processor, however, the user must pass the the `-cpp` option to GHC using `--optghc`.** [emphasis mine]

There are two problems, though. C preprocessor macro expansion you've posted will only work with [GHC 8.0 (or later)](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#options-affecting-the-c-pre-processor) if the package is exposed. It should, however, work with `cabal haddock` or `stack haddock` regardless of GHC's version. The latter variants are recommended if you try to build the documentation of a cabal/stack package, by the way.

If you still know  what you're doing, use `haddock --optghc=-cpp`.

Comment: I obtained my file via `git clone` and my ghc is 7.10.3

Comment: If you've cloned all files, the project should include a `.cabal` file. Use `cabal haddock`.

Comment: Like this?  `cabal haddock --html -o docs` my terminal says `cabal: unrecognized 'haddock' option `-o'`